# How do I make sure the curl request gets the username and password appended via angular?

Tags: angular, curl

I am hosting my angular web application  using static files and running into 401 error .

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:

my web application prompts for username and password when you try to load it,even though I enter the correct username and password I get a 401 error, upon debug I notice the curl request doesn't have the username and password appeneded while requesting,as soon as I add the username and password to the curl request it passes(see below),how do I make sure the curl request gets the username and password appended via angular?

Following is my curl request which is failing

```
curl 'https://ibait.company.com/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js' -XGET -H 'Origin: https://ibait.company.com' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15' -H 'Referer: https://ibait.company.com/'
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>AppleHttpServer/54b48526</center>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as I add username and password to the curl request it passes

```
curl -u username:password 'https://ibait.company.com/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js' -XGET -H 'Origin: https://ibait.company.com' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15' -H 'Referer: https://ibait.company.com/'
```

UPDATE(A sample API call in component.ts)

```
get_radar_lifecycle_data(){
    this.http.get('https://radar-life-cycle.usspk02.hoster.company.com/api/radar_life_cycle',{params})
        .subscribe(response => {
        console.log("radar data:");
         console.log(response);
         this.newPost = response
     });
}
```

Comment: You need to show your angular code where you make your requests to get an answer to this. Read outs from a curl command prompt are useless here

Comment: @bryan60 - I updated the question with one my sample API call in component.js,let me know if you need a specific piece of angular code

Comment: What is that params object

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
get_radar_lifecycle_data(){
    const username = 'username'; // need to really get these values from your form
    const password = 'password';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
    });
    this.http.get('https://radar-life-cycle.usspk02.hoster.company.com/api/radar_life_cycle', {headers, params})
        .subscribe(response => {
        console.log("radar data:");
         console.log(response);
         this.newPost = response
     });
}
```

this pattern will add basic auth headers to your http requests in angular. I can't tell you how to get the username and password without knowing more about how you collect them in your form.

Comment: My biggest concern is why is this issue happening only on safari but not on chrome or firefox,am cluessless about this part

Comment: your question didn't mention anything about a cross browser problem. You gotta post more of your code and fully explain the issue

Comment: I see the following note on the authentication form Once in place, requests through the edge load balancers will be authenticated and will set a header `X-Forwarded-User` to communicate the username to the application instances.` ,how do I retreive the username and password from `X-Forwarded-User`

Comment: It also says `The proxy filters the actual username and password and instead communicates just the username with the successful auth.` ,so am confused as to how to move forward, after I enter the username and password the expectation is the server validates the username and password and just send the username on a successful auth

Comment: Also as I was saying I see behaviour only on safari ,loading my webapplication on chrome and firefox works great,loading on safari takes it to a blank page ,looking in the `web inspector` shows a 401 error.I can share more of my angular code but what is that you like to see ,where to start ? `index.html` ,`app-routing.module.ts` , `modules .ts ` files etc., any help is truly appreciated